# Как в запрос к MySQL поставить переменную

Tags: php, mysql

Как вместо слова Бухарова вставить переменную?

```
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int FROM datacenter WHERE surname = 'Бухарова'");

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {

     echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];

   }
```

Comment:     "SELECT name, surname FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname'"
    

А как вместо name и surname вставить переменную?

Comment: "SELECT name, ".$varible."FROM datacenter WHERE surname = ".$var.""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$surname = "Бухарова";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname'");
```

Comment: Для ухода от возможных проблем с кавычками, если значение из локального окружения, и для избежания SQL-инъекций, если значение берется из GET или POST, есть смысл поставить экранирование `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: 'SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int FROM datacenter WHERE surname = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($surname) .'"';

Answer (score 1):

или в '$foo' или без них, без разницы

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int FROM datacenter WHERE surname = $foo");

Comment: Как это без разницы?

Comment: Сколько раз писал, никогда проблем не возникало.

Comment: Быть такого не может! Строка всегда должна быть в кавычках. Учите матчасть.

Comment: Не знаю, во всяком случае у меня работало, и я был доволен

Comment: Не могло оно у вас работать. Повторюсь, строка всегда должна быть в кавычках. Без кавычек SQL-парсер будет пытаться проанализировать ее как набор SQL-операторов или названий таблиц, колонок и т.д.

Comment: Такой вариант может работать(у меня работал), так как строка запроса вначале обрабатывается функцией mysql_query(...), а уже потом передаётся SQL парсеру. А PHP $var воспринимает как переменную.

Comment: `mysql_query()` - не асинхронная функция. И передача строки с запросом, и его разбор сервером, и компиляция, и выборка и подготовка результата - все в одном флаконе функции `mysql_query()`. Поэтому ошибку SQL-синтаксиса он вернет не выходя из нее.

Answer (score 0):

На счет подстановки переменных, СРАЗУ делайте правильно, а правильно значит переменную перед постановкой нужно хорошенько отфильтровать (это относится, если вы переменный подставляете из всяческих ПОСТ и ГЕТ запросов)
я лично пользуюсь **php placeholder** 
пример

```
$query = sql_placeholder('select * from users where email=? and password=? limit 1', $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);
```

Довольно удобно если что вот он: http://dklab.ru/chicken/nablas/demo/placeholder/Placeholder.php