# как передать ID в функцию?

Tags: php

```
function Delete ($d){
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
    if ($id) {
        $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE `id` = '" . (int)$id . "'";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
        die('id:' . $id . ' удалено');
    }
}
delete();
```

Comment: в какую функцию?

Comment: Закрыть этот вопрос надо: [487924](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487924/256824), [435981](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435981/256824), [162366](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/162366/256824), [55113](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/55113/256824) и т.д. [Аргументы функции](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функцию необходимо передать ещё и соединение.
Пример с подготовленными выражениями:

```
function delById($link, $id) {
  $sql = 'DELETE FROM Users WHERE id = ?';
  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
    $affected = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    return $affected;
  }
  return false;
}

$id = $_GET['id'] ?? false;
$deleted = $id ? delById($id) : false;
echo $deleted ? "$deleted user deleted" : "Nothing deleted";
```

Answer (score -3):

Вы можете использовать конкатенацию строк, так же как использовали при создании SQL запроса:

```
die('id:' . $id . ' удалено');
```

Comment: можете в коде показать?

Comment: Так я показал уже в коде. Или вы в функцию mysqli_query() пытаетесь передать $id? Если так, то вы его туда уже передали при инициализации переменной $query.

Comment: запись не удаляется из БД

Comment: "Запись не удаляется" и "как передать в фуцнкцию" - это два разных вопроса. Надо сначала определиться со своей проблемой, а потом задавать вопрос

Comment: Проверьте ответ от сервера и поймете в чем ошибка. $id в mysqli_query() вы явно передаете. Для того что бы понять точно, проверьте что находится в $query после ее инициализации: у вас стоит проверка на существование isset($_GET['id']) , но GET['id'] может прийти пустым.

Comment: То же самое касается и ответов. Если вопрос плохо сформулирован, то не надо гадать, надо дождаться нормального вопроса.

Comment: Запись не удаляется по причине не связанной с предоставленным кодом. Сделайте `mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link))` и узнаете причину.

Answer (score -3):

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE `id` = '$id'";
```

Оно и так сработать должно.